# Can you declare object types in struct

Tags: c#

I'm really new to c# coming from c++ background I'm struggling to work with data structures in c++ I used to do that for example

```
struct product {
  int weight;
  double price;
} apple[10];
```

now the problem c# won't let me do the same because in c# when I declare an object type like apple I can't access the weight or the price now  .  is there a way to declare object type array ? like above I know I can do that

```
product apple = new product();
```

but I receive an error cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type Program.product . 
is there a way to apply indexing with data structures all I want to do is something like this .

```
struct product {
  int x;
  double w;
} array[10];

for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ){

array[i].x = array[i - 1].x

}
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Be aware that the difference between `struct` and `class` in .NET is far more important than the difference between the two in C++. They use the same names but they are *not* the same concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Members variables are private by default in C#, so you need to add public before type and name.

Also to create an array you need to use the new keyword.

```
public struct product 
{
  public int x;
  public double w;
}

var products = new product[10];

for (int i = 1 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
{
  products [i].x = products [i - 1].x; // beware 0-1 = -1
}
```

Instances of structs are value types, instead of instances of classes that are references to objects (hidden *managed* pointers to forget to manage them).

This may help you:

[struct (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct)

Comment: Thanks It's working exactly what I wanted  but sometimes depending on the source code I get an error saying the contextual keyword var may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script mode

Comment: Yes, var cannot be used in the scope of a class or a struct. It's a syntactic sugar for local variables when the compiler can infer the type from the right part of the assignment expression: [var (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var).